# Looking up values from many tables based on value in each column

Tags: postgresql

I have several tables containing key value pairs for differint fields in my database. I also have a table that that contains the keys of these differint tables that should be selected as the value for that key. However, I can't figure out how to select these values from the multiple tables?

The tables

```
CREATE TABLE CHARACTERS(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE MEDIA(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE EPISODES(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  MEDIAID INTEGER,
  NAME VARCHAR(64)
);
-- Selecting from this table
CREATE TABLE APPS(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  CHARID INTEGER,
  EPISODEID INTEGER,
  MEDIAID INTEGER
);
```

I am selecting from the `APPS` table, and I want to replace the value of the `*ID` columns with the value of the name in the accomping table's `NAME` column. I want this done for each row in the `APPS` table. Like so...

```
CHARID    -> CHARACTERS.NAME
EPISODEID -> EPISODES.NAME
MEDIAID   -> MEDIA.NAME
```

I have tried to use joins, but they don't do it for each row in the `APPS` table. I have 18 rows in the `APPS` table, but I only get back way less than I have in the table or way more than I have in the table. So how can I make it do it for each row in the `APPS` table?

Comment: Please elaborate on `but they don't do it for each row in the APPS table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do by `JOIN`ing the tables together and selecting the desired columns from the individual tables:

```
SELECT c.name AS character_name, e.name AS episode, m.name AS media
FROM apps a
LEFT JOIN episodes e ON e.id = a.episodeid
LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = a.mediaid
LEFT JOIN characters c ON c.id = a.charid;
```

If you want to present the rows in a specific order, you can specify that too as a final clause in the `SELECT` statement. You can use any field from the included tables; that field is not necessarily part of the columns selected:

```
ORDER BY a.id -- order by apps.id
```

or

```
ORDER BY e.id, c.name -- order first by episode id, then by character name
```

etc

Comment: This does not do this for each row in the 'APPS' table

Comment: That probably means that for same values of `apps.episodeid`, `apps.mediaid` or `apps.charid` you have no data. Use `LEFT JOIN`s instead. See updated answer. You will get `NULL` values for the attributes where you are missing data.